# jQuery Mobile: how to detect when one moving image hovering over the button

Tags: jquery-mobile, hover, mouseover

In my mobile app, I need to move a green image around the web page.
When the green image hover over the submit button, the button will show "Submit?", and when the user droped the green image on the submit button, the button will turn to orange.

Here's the pictures:

[image: The first picture is when the users droped the green image]

[image: The second shows when the green image hovers over the button, what the button should show]

**The problem** is when the green image hover over the button, the button cannot change, only when I touch the button it can change. I have tried hover() and mouseover() method, all didn't work. It is **jQuery Mobile**, in my PC version, everything worked very well, but mobile app is different.

**So, what can I do so that when the green image hovering over the button, it can show "Submit?"? Or is there any way to detect the object is Yes or No button when the green image hoving over one of them?**

here's the code: The drag and drop methods are from another JS file, but should not influence this question.

```
id = "html";
    $(id).ready(function (e) {

$('.yes').bind('mouseover', function( event, ui ){
    $('.yes').attr("src","images/submit_confirm.png");
    $('input[name=stimulusResponse]').val("yes");
    $('.no').attr("src","images/no.png");
});
$('.no').mouseover(function( event, ui ){
    $('.no').attr("src","images/submit_confirm.png");
    $('input[name=stimulusResponse]').val("no");
    $('.yes').attr("src","images/yes.png");
});

$('.bottomGoButton').drag(function( ev, dd ){
    $( this ).css({
        top: dd.offsetY,
        left: dd.offsetX
    });
    $(this).bind('vmousemove', function(event) {
        $('input[name=test]').val(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY + $('input[name=test]').val());
    });
});

$('.no').drop(function(){
     $('input[name=stimulusResponse]').val("no");
     $('.no').attr("src","images/submitted_no.png");         
});

$('.yes').drop(function(){
     $('input[name=stimulusResponse]').val("yes");
     $('.yes').attr("src","images/submitted_yes.png");       
});
```

});

Comment: @Omar  Attached the code already

Comment: Replace `$('HTML').ready` with `$(document).on('pageinit', function(e)`

Comment: Still doesn't work, even use $(document).bind('pageinit', function(e)) doesn't work either~~@Omar

Comment: It works on pc right?

Comment: @Omar  yes, only on PC

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Omar   no errors, I have solved this problem right now, by using a totally different way, blow is my solution, with the help of jQuery position(), width(), height() methods, things like hover(), drop() can be done easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself by using the position of the button and the mouse to do each operation, this have added more flexibility.

Here's part of the code: 
1. this is the way to get the top, left, right, bottom arguments:

```
var yesPosition = $('.yes').position(), noPosition = $('.no').position(),
                yesWidth = $('.yes').width(), yesHeight = $('.yes').height(),
                noWidth = $('.no').width(), noHeight = $('.no').height();
            //get the relative position of yes/no button
            var yesTop = yesPosition.top, yesLeft = yesPosition.left, 
                yesBottom = yesTop + yesHeight, yesRight = yesLeft + yesWidth,
                noTop = noPosition.top, noLeft = noPosition.left,
                noBottom = noTop + noHeight, noRight = noLeft + noWidth;
```

/*2. this is a replace of hover() method, only when the mouse is moving and in the range of one of the button, we can do the operations we want, pretty cool right :)*/

```
if(isMouseUp == false && event.pageX >= yesLeft && event.pageX <= yesRight && event.pageY >= yesTop && event.pageY <= yesBottom) {
                            $('input[name=test]').val("X: " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY); 
                            $('.yes').attr("src","images/submit_confirm.png");
                            $('input[name=stimulusResponse]').val("yes hover");
                            $('.no').attr("src","images/no.png");
                        }
                        else if (isMouseUp == false && event.pageX >= noLeft && event.pageX <= noRight && event.pageY >= noTop && event.pageY <= noBottom) {
                            $('input[name=test]').val("X: " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY); 
                            $('.no').attr("src","images/submit_confirm.png");
                            $('input[name=stimulusResponse]').val("no hover");
                            $('.yes').attr("src","images/yes.png");
                        }
                        else {
                            $('input[name=stimulusResponse]').val("");
                            $('.yes').attr("src","images/yes.png");
                            $('.no').attr("src","images/no.png");
                        }
```